# printing the word that is written multiple times 1 time

Tags: c

I have an array as this:

```
array[][100]={"pencil","pen","book","eraser","pen","bag","bag","pencil",......}
```

If there is more than one of the same word in the array, I want to print this only once.(result= pencil pen book eraser bag).How can I do this usig array[i]?Thanks...

Comment: a simple solution is to use two nested loops and inside them use `strcmp`, a complex solution may involve creating a hash-map (actually this is a much better algorithm). and, if you're free to use C++ then it may be of just 10-20 lines in total...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. I haven't worked much on its memory optimisation though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

int main() {
    char arr[][MAXLEN] = {"pencil", "pen", "book", "eraser", "pen", "bag", "bag", "pencil"};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), c = 0, inArray = 0, i, j;
    char **result = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i] = malloc(MAXLEN);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        inArray = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            if (!strcmp(arr[i], result[j])) {
                inArray = 1;
                break;
            }
        if(!inArray)
            strcpy(result[c++], arr[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        printf("%s ", result[i]);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't use struct and malloc

Comment: @davidcooper okay you can check out [this code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CbT8samBib7oFCcR). Here I have used the non-standard VLAs. If you're not using `gcc` then you may need to change `n` to `8` to make the code work. I hadn't used structures by the way...

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array in O(n log n) time and then loop over it skipping entries that equal their predecessor (though the result would be sorted - `bag, book, eraser, pen, pencil` -, not sure if you are happy with that)

Comment: I don't think it is gonna exactly be an O(n logn) operation to sort an array of strings. String comparison is not O(1) operation like integers.